# Reference for regularity of heat equation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, heat-equation

Consider a Gelfand triple $V\subseteq H$, together $f=f_1+f_2 \in L^2(0,T,H) + H^1(0,T,V^{*}) $ and a symmetric and bounded, coercive operator $A: V\rightarrow V^*$.

Consider the heat equation

$$u'+Au=f$$
$$u(0)=0$$

I know (and have proved) that under the given hypothesis, one gets $u'\in L^2(0,T,H)$.

> Are you aware of a good reference for this fact?

I need to cite this result in a paper, so as to avoid putting a proof of this fact.

---

*Sketch of proof*

I will refer to [this set of notes](https://mate.unipv.it/gilardi/WEBGG/PSPDF/parastr.pdf). We assume $V$ is separable, hence, take $V_1\subset V_2 \subset... \subset V$ such that $\bigcup_n V_n$ is dense in $V$. Choose a basis $v_1^n,...,v_{m_n}^n$ of $V_n$ and represent $u$ as $u_n = \sum_{j=1}^{m_n}u_jv_j$. Here, $u_j=u_j(t)$.

We use the Galerkin method and find a hopefully convergent sequence if $u_n$ satisfying
$$\langle u_n'+Au_n-f,v \rangle_{V^*,V} = 0, \text{ for all } v\in V_n \text{ and a.e. in }(0,T)$$

*Lemma*. We can then reason as in [1](https://mate.unipv.it/gilardi/WEBGG/PSPDF/parastr.pdf) (see (57) at page 23, but I believe this is standard) to obtain

$$||u_n||_{L^2(0,T,V)}^2\leq||u_n||_{C([0,T],H)}^2+||u_n||_{L^2(0,T,V)}^2\leq c ||f||_{L^2(0,T,V^*)}^2$$

*Proof of the claimed result (with $f_1=0$)*. Test the defition of $u_n$ with $u_n'$ and integrate:

$$\int_0^t||u_n'||_H^2+\int_0^t \langle Au_n,u_n'\rangle_{V^*,V}=\int_0^t \langle f_2,u_n'\rangle_{V^*,V}$$

Let $\alpha$ be the coercivity constant of $A$. We find

$$\int_0^t \langle Au_n,u_n'\rangle_{V^*,V} \geq \frac{\alpha}{2}||u_n(t)||_V^2$$

By integrating by parts we see

$$\int_0^t \langle f_2,u_n'\rangle_{V^*,V} = -\int_0^t \langle f_2',u_n\rangle_{V^*,V} + \langle f_2(t),u_n(t)\rangle_{V^*,V}$$

Hence Young's inequality yields, for $0<\epsilon<\alpha/2$:

$$|\int_0^t \langle f_2,u_n'\rangle_{V^*,V}| = \frac{1}{2}||u_n||^2_{L^2(0,T,V)} + \frac{1}{2}||f_2'||^2_{L^2(0,T,V^*)} + \epsilon||u_n(t)||_V^2+ \epsilon^{-1}||f_2(t)||^2_{V^*}$$

Combining everything we get
$$\int_0^t||u_n'||_H^2\leq (\frac{\alpha}{2}-\epsilon)||u_n(t)||_V^2 + \int_0^t||u_n'||_H^2\leq \frac{1}{2}||u_n||^2_{L^2(0,T,V)} + \frac{1}{2}||f_2'||^2_{L^2(0,T,V^*)}$$

Using the lemma, we see that $u_n'$ weakly converges to something in $L^2(0,T,H)$, modulo subsequences. But one can show  (see e.g. the lemma again, and the fact that $A$ is bounded) that the whole $u_n'$ converges to $u'$, weakly and in the $L^2(0,T,V^*)$ sense.  Therefore, $u'\in L^2(0,T,H)$.

Comment: I doubt that this result is true. If $f$ is just in $H^1(0,T;V^*)$ (i.e. $f_1=0$) then $u'$ is in $L^2(0,T;V^*)$ and not in $L^2(0,T;H)$. I believe that this result is sharp. Can you please sketch your proof?

Comment: @daw Hi, I have added a sketch of the proof.

Comment: It seems to me you forgot the term $\langle u_n(0), f_2(0)\rangle$ in your integration by parts. Moreover your sketch of proof would be better if you precise at each step if the duality bracket is the $H$ or the $V-V^\ast$ one.

Comment: @ToleG You are right. But this is a lapsus, as in my application, $u_0=0$. Let me incorporate this, and the other suggestion, in my answer.

Comment: Looks good (up to typos: in the last inequality $f_2$ is missing in first part). So the key seems to be that $u(0) \in V$ is required, otherwise the integration by parts in $f_2\cdot u'$ does not work. Not sure where to look for references, as this is some kind of intermediate regularity between weak solutions ($u'\in L^2(V^*)$) and higher regularity $u\in L^2(D(A))$ and $u'\in L^2(H)$.